# Get Set ID from List in Batch Class

Tags: apex, batch, map, set

The ws_contact_callout class expects a SET of ids.  in the Execute methods I attempt to get it but within the loop but the compiler is complaining.

How can/should I get the Set of ids without requery?

```
public class sync_mdm_contact_batch_V2 implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, 
                                              Database.Stateful , Database.AllowsCallouts
{
 public integer recordCount = 0;

 public Database.QueryLocator start (Database.BatchableContext bc)
 {
    return Database.getQueryLocator('SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE RecordType.DeveloperName = \'xxx\'');
 }

 public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Contact> scope)
 {
    //variable does not exist: records
    Set<Id> ids = new Map<Id, Contact>(records).keySet();

    //process each batch of contacts
    for (id recordid : ids)
    {
        //method does not exist on incorrect signature:  void future_callout(id) from the type ws_mdm_contact
        //Signature for ws_mdm_contact.future_callout(Set<ID> ids)
        ws_mdm_contact.future_callout(recordid);

        //increment recordsProcessed
        recordCount += ids.size();
    }
 }

 public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc)
 {
    system.debug(recordCount + 'records processed');

    AsyncApexJob job =
        [   SELECT Id, Status, NumberOfErrors, JobItemsProcessed, TotalJobItems, CreatedBy.Email
            FROM AsyncApexJob
            WHERE Id = :bc.getJobId()
        ];
    //email
    emailManager.sendMail('email', 'subject', string.valueof(recordCount));
 }
}
```

This is my first attempt at a batch class following the trailhead example with a twist.  In the Execute method I want to be able to send 100 records (set of ids) to my class which does my callouts.  If I rightly understand things I can have up to 100 callouts.  So this should get me 100 records x 100 callouts aka 10000 records.

reported issue:

Getting closer I can almost taste it.
I updated the code to reflect current state and commented where it is complaining.  The endpoint is constructed to only handle one record at time so I think I need to do the loop vs a bulkcall.

Comment: What is the compiler complaining about ?

Comment: Invalid initializer type Contact found for Map<Id,Contact>: expected a Map with the same key and value types, or a valid SObject List  and  Variable does not exist: contactMap

Comment: @Daryn do you need to create a set of contact ids within the loop?

Comment: I think the querylocator gets me the qualified list of contacts.  Signature for ws_mdm_contact.future_callout(Set<ID> ids).  So I am thinking I need to take the results which looks like forces into List<Contact> and convert that into a Set that the callout class is expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to create a set of ids within the loop in the following way.

```
Set<Id> contactIds = new Set<Id>();
for (Contact C : scope) {
    contactIds.add(c.Id); // this is what you need here to add the contact ids
    //increment recordsProcessed
    recordsProcessed ++;
}

ws_contact_callout(contactids); // perform other operation only after you have added the ids in the loop
```

Comment: Thanks I will not be able to try this out until I return to office but I will definitely try it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all the ids, make one callout per, then increment your record count:

```
Set<Id> recordIds = new Map<Id, Contact>(scope).keySet();
for (Id recordId : recordIds)
{
    // make callout
}
recordCount += recordIds.size();
```

**Original Explanations Below**

You need to ***pass in the entire scope*** to your constructor. It accepts a collection (`List<SObject>`), not a single record (`SObject`).

**Incorrect**

```
for (Contact record : records)
{
    Set<Id> ids = new Map<Id, Contact>(record);
}
```

**Correct**

```
Set<Id> ids = new Map<Id, Contact>(records).keySet();
```

If you need to pass each `Id` individually to your callout, you can loop over the collection:

```
for (Id recordId : ids)
{
    makeIndividualCallout(recordId);
}
```

Otherwise you can just make one call:

```
makeBulkCallout(ids);
```

And finally, you can simply increment your count by the size of the collection:

```
recordCount += ids.size();
```

Comment: reported issue:

Getting closer I can almost taste it. I updated the code to reflect current state and commented where it is complaining. The endpoint is constructed to only handle one record at time so I think I need to do the loop vs a bulkcall.